# Rails Exception notifier is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I installed the exception notification plugin from http://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/master

I can confirm that my ActionMailer is working as I received emails from other process. Although, I can see the notifier sending the email in the log (Sent mail to my@email.address )
and the email address was written correct, I didn't get any emails about the exceptions.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: And you've confirmed that there are, in fact, exceptions, correct?

Sounds like a silly question, but there are silly people out there...

Comment: Yes, I created the map.errors in the route.rb and point to an non-exist controller , I sal the 500.html page but no emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem been addressed, http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/eaf210a7d099ad57

I just copied the plugin from a old project, and it works fine straightaway.